# How can I provide public access to my photos

Tags: javascript, google-photos, google-photos-api

I would like to build a small js library that can read a specific album from my account and display the photos within as a slideshow.

In this guide (https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started), to access the API we need both ClientID and Secret. Is there any way to access the API using some type of public key for read-only access? That way I (the provider of photos) don't have to login every time?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Photos Library API is used via OAuth2 user authentication. All requests through the API are made on behalf of a user. Public API keys or service accounts are not supported.

OAuth tokens expire after a certain time, which is returned as part of the OAuth authentication request. You can use a **refresh token** to retrieve a new access token once it has expired. If you'd like to do this without explicit interactive user interaction, your application needs to be authorized for offline access. The good news is that the authentication client libraries handle this for you.

If you are using Google Sign-In (for example on Android), you can check if the user has already signed in using `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)`, so you would not need to prompt again for access. You could also [enable server-side access](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) if you want to make these offline requests from your backend.

If you are using any of the [Google OAuth client libraries](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#libraries), you can specify the 'offline' parameter as part of the initial sign-in request. For example in Java, you would set the access type: `.setAccessType("offline")` on the `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder` during creation.

Comment: Will there be a Node.js client library for Google Photos in the future? I was thinking of implementing a photo gallery on my website with the help of Firebase' cloud functions.

Comment: @individual8 - a Node.js client library is something that's on our radar, but we don't have a timeline for it. You can make straight HTTP calls directly to the REST API from node.js, for example using the request library. We have an example on GitHub here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-photos

Comment: I played with the REST API already. But the issue of implementing OAuth token retrieval after an access token expires seemed to much hassle. Any pointers how I can solve this easily are greatly appreciated.